# Craft 3: Non-Admin Users Can't Login

Tags: craft3, login, user-groups

Here's an odd one: I have a site with many users, only a few of them admins. Any admin user can login either via the /admin control panel or through a frontend login, which follows [the example from the documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html).

Any non-admin users will be rebuffed on either login with an "Invalid username or password" message. Even more odd, if an admin user attempts to "Login as" a non-admin user from the control panel, it simply takes them back to the dashboard with a "Logged In" message, but keeps them logged in as their original admin role.

Any ideas on what maybe to look for or test?

Comment: In case you're wondering, a non-admin user can be given all the privileges of an admin user, but it still won't log them in. Being in the admin group is the only way the login forms will work.

Comment: You have any plugins installed hooking into the login process by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've realized that this was a plugin issue, that changes everything. Thanks for the lead, Brad.